# How can I put mysql databases in different disk partitions (linux - Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, mysql, database, partition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multiple file systems for mysql](https://serverfault.com/questions/137486/multiple-file-systems-for-mysql)

hi,

How can I put mysql databases in different partition (linux - Ubuntu)?

Thanks,
yosef

Answer (score 5):

Create the new partition and filesystem.  Mount it somewhere.  Stop mysql and copy the entire contents of `/var/lib/mysql` to the new location. Be sure to preserve permissions and ownership.

You now have a few options (all assuming you mounted the new filesystem in `/opt/mysql_data`:

1. Delete `/var/lib/mysql` and create a symlink from it to the new directory.  For example:

   ```
   ln -s /opt/mysql_data /var/lib/mysql
   ```
2. Create a file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d` called "local_configs.cnf" and put the following lines in that file:

   ```
   [mysqld]
   datadir=/opt/mysql_data
   ```
3. After the data is copied, mount the new filesystem directly on `/var/lib/mysql`.

Whichever path you take, when you start mysql back up again it will be using the new location.

Comment: can I install directly on 2ndary location instead of moving?

Comment: If you build your own mysql package, sure. Some package managers may have hooks for modifying this, but I haven't looked into it. The easiest would be to create /var/lib/mysql and mount a new device on it prior to beginning the install.

Comment: On some distributions, including Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, AppArmor will get in your way. This will be visible using `journalctl -xe` which will give `Denied` messages. To avoid this, declare your change to AppArmor, as described at https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/apparmor_and_mysql . In short, to put it on `/data`, add two lines to `etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` (Cannot put them in a comment since it only supports inline markdown), the reload apparmor.

Comment: would there be a 2018 solution to this answer?  It appears that this solution is good, but just a little outdated.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me, specifically option #2. I also had to run `sudo chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql`, `sudo chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql`, and `sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql` to get the permissions right, otherwise systemctl was failing to start the service.

Answer (score 2):

See [multiple file systems for mysql](https://serverfault.com/questions/137486/multiple-file-systems-for-mysql)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.